# Why does my page instantly scroll down each time I reload the site? Also how can I place "About Me" further down?

Tags: html, css

So I added smooth scrolling and a button that scrolls you to the bottom and that's the point but now every time I load in and reload the site etc. it automatically scrolls down. I also want to put the "About me" heading further down so it isn't visible unless you click "Click to learn more"

Picture of the site: https://i.gyazo.com/79313e6ee1fe3de82d18b33f238ac5d9.jpg

```html
<div class="banner">
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Samples</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<div class="content">           
    <h1>THE COPY THAT INTRIGUES BUT DONT DECEIVE</h1>


<div class="About">
    <a href="#down"><button type="button"><span></span><b>CLICK TO LEARN MORE</button></a>
        <div id="down">
            <h1>About me</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: There's lots of info out there about (some) browsers or other systems remembering the scrolling position. The first one that came up on my search was https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284049/how-does-a-browser-remember-the-scroll-state#:~:text=More%20specifically%2C%20it%27s%20a%20get%2Fset%20property%20on%20the,page%2C%20the%20browser%20recalls%20the%20scroll%20bar%20position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't understand what you want to say provide `CSS` for easy to understand your problem.
2. Set `#down` as default `display: none`  and then add script(see my code) and also add `onclick="show()"` in button element,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Intriguing Copy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="navbar">
            <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Samples</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<div class="content">           
    <h1>THE COPY THAT INTRIGUES BUT DONT DECEIVE</h1>


<div class="About">
    <a href="#down"><button type="button" onclick="show()"><span></span><b>CLICK TO LEARN MORE</button></a>
        <div id="down">
            <h1>About me</h1>
        </div>
        <script>
            function show() {
                document.getElementById("down");
                down.style.display = "block";
            }
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```html
<a href="#down"><button type="button"><span></span><b>CLICK TO LEARN MORE</button></a>
```

is invalid - you cannot nest interactive elements like that. Either use a [button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) or use an [anchor](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

If your page is automatically scrolling, I'd assume you're reloading the page after clicking this anchor. I suspect that if you look at your browser's navigation bar, it will end with `#down`, like

```
https://whateveryourdomain.is/somepage.html#down
```

That's how [page anchors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) work - the browser will attempt to scroll the page until the matching anchor tag or id'd element is at the top of the viewport.